# Why is "das Büro" neutral?

Tags: article

Is there any specific rule for why the word "Büro" uses the "das"-Artikel or is it just one of those "just memorize it" words?

Comment: Why do you consider the office in any way special compared to other ‘just learn them’ words?

Comment: Why is it "der Löffel", but "die Gabel" and "das Messer"? Genus is just one of those things you have to learn when learning new words, it doesn't follow any rules.

Comment: For some categories of words there are anyway rules (or rules of thumb), e.g. those ending on -ion are usually female. I suppose, the question is if Büro (or Bureau in the older spelling) is part of such a group.

Comment: Well, there are indeed some rules that cover a big amount of words and in case of doubt, you have a good chance to figure the right article. My personal argument is that it is because from the French "bureau" and just germanized and thus an international word and those are mostly "das". I just wanted it confirmed (or denied).

Comment: Here is a nice etymology for the English bureau, which is, of course, based on the French bureau: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bureau   However, it does not help with the genus issue.

Answer (score 0):

Am I misguided considering that many words ending on -o are neuter in German?

> das Büro
>
> das Klo
>
> das Bistro
>
> das Velo
>
> das Chateau [okay, probably in analogy with *das Schloss*]
>
> das Tableau
>
> das Stroh [?! - probably only coincidentally]
>
> das Holdrio [yes, confirmed by Duden; not to be confused with *der Hallodri*]
>
> das Bordereau / das Bordero [however, Duden accepts both *das Bordero* and *der Bordero*]

However

> der Espresso
>
> der Cappuccino
>
> der Bardolino (may also be because of *der Wein*)
>
> der Risotto [Duden says it is *der*, although where I grew up in Germany it is definitely *das* - which Duden calls Austrian]

So, perhaps, words ending on -o unless they are Italian?
No! Because of

> das Allegro
>
> das Allegretto
>
> das Presto
>
> das Largo
>
> das Sforzato
>
> das Diminuendo, das Crescendo

etc.

So, words on -o, unless they are Italian food?

Comment: That would confirm my idea...those words are all (except Stroh) not German, but derived from French (or Italian in the case of Risotto)

Comment: *Stroh* was a joke, anyway. For *Risotto*, *Der Duden* suggests *der Risotto* and claims that *das Risotto* was in use only in Austria. Which I doubt, as I am from Germany (okay, grown up in the South) and we say *das Risotto* there.

Comment: So obviously pretty much every word ending on -o and all of them are originally not German. I am German myself, I was just having a discussion with my (non-German) wife about this, that's why i wanted to confirm the rules here. Indeed, the Duden allows also "der Risotto" which sounds totally awkward to me. I would, myself, also only say "das Risotto".

Comment: *Der Espresso* and *der Cappucino* obviously because they are just *der Kaffee*.

Comment: If you are looking for patterns, it seems that French foreign words ending in -eau (which are always male in French, because French doesn't have a neuter gender) become neuter in German (and turn to -o over time). *Chateau* derives from *castellum*, and it's also "das Schloss", so that makes sense. The etymology of the other examples in this group seems more complicated.

Comment: der Po, der Dildo, der Euro, der Flamenco, der Latino, der Maestro, der Mephisto, der Mafioso, der/die Mambo, der Kosovo, der Trafo, der Porno, der Oregano, der Pluto, der/das Storno, der Tango, der Tornado, der Torso, der Zoo, der Voodoo — größtenteils lateinischen Ursprungs, aber ich hab das Gefühl es gibt kaum germanische Wörter, die auf O enden. Soweit ich das richtig überblicke, ist auch keines der Wörter in deiner Antwort germanisch. (Ausnahme: Stroh)

Comment: Die Wörter in der ersten Gruppe sind (nahezu) alle französischem Ursprung. "Holdrio" weiß ich nicht genau. Das Wort ist aber sowohl neutrum als auch maskulin.

Comment: Bitte löschen. Die Antwort ist schlichtweg falsch.

Comment: @Em1. Schöne Liste. Bei Kosovo ist jedoch anzumerken: In der Tat wird das oft als *der Kosovo* bezeichnet, doch jedem slavisch Sprachkundigen sträubt sich das Rückenfell, denn in allen slavischen Sprachen sind auf -o endende Substantive sächlich. Also *das Kosovo*. Ich meine, dass Zeitungen,die Wert auf Qualität legen, das auch so benützen.

Comment: @Em1. Zum Holdrio noch: Mein Duden (Universalwörterbuch, ca. 2000 Seiten) nennt hier nur neutrum. Wo findest du es als maskulinum? Oder verwechselst du es mit *der Hallodri*?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Online-Duden. Es gibt zwei Bedeutungen, oder eher zwei Wörter. Das eine ist sächlich, das andere ist maskulin.

Comment: Ah, ja, ich sehe. Zweite Bedeutung (bei Gebrauch des Worts im Maskulinum) "der Holdrio" (veraltet) = "der Leichtfuß". Man lernt nie aus. Holareiduliö!

Comment: @Em1 Bei Personenbezeichnungen ist _-o_ ganz klar männlich und daher maskulin. _Po_ ist kurz für _Podex_, _Trafo_ für _Transformator_, _Zoo_ für _Zoologischer Garten_.

Comment: *Der Bajazzo*...(jedoch venezianischer Herkunft, doch nichts Essbares).

Answer (score -2):

Yes *Büro* derives also from the French. In the 19th century it was still written *Bureau* even in German, cf. [Brockhaus](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=123085). Note, that the word can mean the room as well as the group of people working there, see [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Buero), e. g. in

> Das ganze Büro war in Aufruhr.

Especially in the latter meaning neuter is really convincing.

Comment: Still, *bureau* being of French origin anyway does not explain neuter, or does it?

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Answer (score -2):

Integration of loanwords in Germany usually works using the article of the appropriate meaning in the target language. During that time *Bureau* has most likely been associated with a German word which has the article "das".

Comment: Dann wäre es "die Klo(sett)" und "die Bistro", um einfach mal zwei andere (mehr oder weniger direkt) aus dem franz. entlehnte Wörter zu nehmen. Wobei die Grundaussage deiner Antwort grundsätzlich richtig ist. Das Problem ist hier vielmehr die Frage.

Comment: Bei Klo(sett) und Bistro muss man erforschen, was das deutsche Bezugswort bei der Bildung des Artikels war. Es heißt z.B. "Die SMS" wegen "Die Nachricht".

Comment: @äüö: In Österreich aber »das SMS« und (vorwiegend) auch »das E-Mail« (und *das Joghurt, das Cola, das Keks* aber *der Spray, der Radio, der Gummi* und *die Ausschank, die Schneid*). Alle Regeln, die du aus der Analyse der im deutschen Deutsch üblichen Genus-Zuordnungen einfallen, musst du immer auch mit den österreichischen Zuordnungen abgleichen. In vielen Fällen gibt es schlichtweg keine Regel.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich habe meine Antwort auf Deutschland eingegrenzt, da hier diese Regel greift.

Answer (score -3):

If in doubt you can fall back on.

Der --> männlich

Die --> weiblich

Das --> neutrum

As a Büro is not a living thing and therefore gender neutral you could call it das. But that is just one of the many rules that you could use to explain something that essentially follows culture/tradition.

Also see der Arbeitsraum vs. das Arbeitszimmer. Both refer to the same thing, just using a different compund word which in essence then determins the article being use.d